# Connecting to MySql using Java - SSL Connection

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I have been trying to to connect to MySql data base which uses ssl connection with java and having trouble, if any one can help me will be of great help.

Manual Connection to MySql:

We use MySQL Workbench , parameters - Hostname - "test-db1-ro-xxxxxx.net" , Port - 3306 , User Name , Password.
There is a SSL CA File - mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem , the manual connection is successful.

I tried the same in java (in windows system)
My code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://test-db1-ro.apdev.XXXXXX.net:3306/database";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
String userName = "XXXXXXXX"; 
String password = "XXXXXXXX";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
```

when i run the code i get an error as "Access Denied"
I am thinking it is due to the SSL Connection.

I am not able to know how to use the .pem file to make a secure connection to database in this case.

Can some one help, have done various things but always get the same access denied error.

Full StackTrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'xxxxxxxx' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at TestDBConnection.main(TestDBConnection.java:34)
```

Comment: you can start by reading this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Comment: Created a keystore with the .pem file and then changed my code as below, but still get an issue.
Can you think of anything else?

String url = "jdbc:mysql://test-db1-ro.apdev.XXXXX.net:3306/database" + "&useSSL=true" + "&requireSSL=true" ;
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace, or whatever error message the "access denied" is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have trouble authenticating.
On the MySql terminal:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If problem still persists:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This command grants you superuser privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To make sure your privileges are loaded.

**NB:** Do not use this account on websites with public access.