# Can't connect to MySQL from Java Spring app even if it works from the console

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Spring Boot app that attempts to connect to a MySQL DB. That's what I have in the application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://my_host:3306/my_db
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=my_pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'my_host.my_domain' (using password: YES)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:625) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:937) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:947) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.mydomain.myspringapp.Receiver.receiveMessage(Receiver.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-jms-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'my_host.my_domain' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1714) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2190) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

I manage to connect from the console using

```
mysql -u my_user -h my_host -p --database my_db
```

If I use the wrong password in the console I am getting the same message that I get in Java:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'my_host.my_domain' (using password: YES)
```

This might hint at the password not being correctly sent, but I have checked the charsets and it seems it's UTF8 both in Java/Spring and the database.

```
+----------------------------+
| default_character_set_name |
+----------------------------+
| utf8                       |
+----------------------------+
```

I wasn't the one who installed the DB and I don't have admin rights on it.

Furthermore I have attempted to config a proprietary Java app that normally takes the connection properties and can connect to a bunch of different DBs, but it also failed. So it most likely has nothing to do with my code in Java and it's a config/privileges issue, most likely in MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Give permission to user using mysql workbench

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942139/connecting-to-mysql-using-java-ssl-connection

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems recently. The problem is a white space at the end of password.

spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=my_pass<**remove spaces**>